# Default output directory for logback

Tags: tomcat, slf4j, logback

I cant find out, where my log file is. On linux, the file is in tomcat /logs directory as expected with other tomcat's logs. On Windows I do not know, where it is.

This is part of my config (logback.xml) :

```
<appender name="DEBUG_LOG_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>DEBUG</level>
    </filter>
    <file>logs/audioguide-debug.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>logs/audioguide-debug.log.%i.zip</fileNamePattern>
        <minIndex>1</minIndex>
        <maxIndex>20</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger | %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

When I put absolute address it works, but I would like to have same file working on both platforms :

```
<appender name="DEBUG_LOG_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>DEBUG</level>
    </filter>
    <file>c:\programy\apache-tomcat-8.0.26\logs\audioguide-debug.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>c:\programy\apache-tomcat-8.0.26\logs\audioguide-debug.log.%i.zip</fileNamePattern>
        <minIndex>1</minIndex>
        <maxIndex>20</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger | %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a non-absolute path is given in the `<file>` attribute, it's always related to the current working directory of the process that Logback runs in (in your case, Tomcat).

If I'm guessing correctly, in Windows you're running Tomcat from an IDE. In Eclipse, you can see the working directory through "Run configurations", on the "Arguments" tab. In Intellij 14, it's somewhere in `%USERPROFILE%\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\<configuration name>"`.

The usual practice is to use `${catalina.base}\logs` as the logging path. This way you're making the log path explicit and easy to verify.

Comment: thanks for help, but actually it was in different place (/bin? Weird :) )

Comment: No, not at all weird. Have you started Tomcat by executing "start.bat" directly in the ``tomcat\bin`` folder? There, you have it.

Comment: well the weird is that it prints out `Using CATALINA_BASE:   "c:\programy\apache-tomcat-8.0.26"`  (not the /bin folder)

Comment: ``CATALINA_BASE`` and current working directory are two different things. Please reread my post carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I found it, the location is : `...tomcat/bin/logs`.

I started it with `...tomcat/bin/startup`